# How would you remove a number from an unsorted vector using only .at(), .push_back(), .size(), and/or .resize()?

Tags: c++, duplicates, stdvector, function-definition

I'm new to C++ and I'm trying to write a void function that will delete a duplicate from a vector while preserving the order of the vector. I'm having trouble deleting the number from my vector using just .at(), .push_back(), .size(), and .resize(). How would I go about doing this?

This is what I have so far:

```
void RemoveDuplicates(std::vector<int>& vector, int vectorSize) 
{
    int i;
    int j;
    std::vector<int> tempVec; 

    for (i = 0; i < vector.size(); i++)
    {
        for (j = 1; j < vector.size(); j++)
        {
            if (vector.at(i) == vector.at(j))
            {
                tempVec.push_back(vector.at(i));  //Unduplicated Vector
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I were to put "1 2 3 3" in this it returns the tempVec as "2 3 3 3 3." The expected result was just "1 2 3." How would I go about fixing this so that it deduplicates the vector using just those vector manipulators?

Comment: I'm not understanding how you think that adding items that are equal is going to remove duplicates.

Comment: why only .at(), .push_back(), .size(), and .resize() ? why not `std::unique` ?

Comment: I've tried changing it to vector.at(i) != vector.at(j) but that just changes the result from "2 3 3 3 3" to "1 1 1 2 2 3 3." Sorry I'm still quite new to this

Comment: @SleezyChickenbiscuits It's the wrong approach, you cannot tell from examining just two items that they are not duplicates, because even if not equal they could be equal to other items in the vector. Instead you have to check that an item is not equal to **all** the items following in the vector.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple approach, not very efficient but easy to understand

```
void RemoveDuplicates(std::vector<int>& vector) 
{
    std::vector<int> tempVec; 
    for (size_t i = 0; i < vector.size(); i++)
    {
        // look for vector[i] in remainder of vector
        bool found = false;
        for (size_t j = i + 1; j < vector.size(); j++)
        {
            if (vector.at(i) == vector.at(j))
            {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        // if not found it's not a duplicate
        if (!found)
            tempVec.push_back(vector.at(i));
    }
    vector = tempVec;
}
```

Comment: I guess I just didn't understand why you would search the remainder of the sequence for duplicate when you already had your escalating list of "unique" values in `tempVec`. Same concept, just 180-deg opposite approach. You're continually searching a shrinking list of potential duplicates, I'm continually searching a continually growing list of already-reaped values. Same complexity, so not like it matters. Tomato Tomato.

Comment: @WhozCraig The two approaches will result in a different order of the final vector. So maybe there's a reason to pick one or the other. The OP does say 'preserving the order', so there might be an expectation whether to remove duplicates from the front or the back.

Comment: @john Your function is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Building on your current idea, you can compare each value in `vector` with all the values in `tempVec`. If it's not found in `tempVec`, add it.

I'm using range based `for`-loops to simplify the looping:

```cpp
#include <utility> // std::move

void RemoveDuplicates(std::vector<int>& vector) {
    std::vector<int> tempVec; 
    
    for(int in : vector) {       // `in` will be assigned one value at a time from vector
        bool found = false;      // set to `true` if the `in` value has already been seen
        for(int out : tempVec) { // range based for-loop again
            if(in == out) {      // oups, duplicate
                found = true;    // set to true to avoid storing it
                break;           // and abort this inner loop
            }
        }
        // only stored values not found:
        if(not found) tempVec.push_back(in);
    }
    // move assign the result to `vector`:
    vector = std::move(tempVec);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to pass the size of the vector. A vector knows its `size()`. Your code is not actually removing anything from `vector`.

Use the tools available to you.

You can use `std::unique` to remove duplicate adjacent elements. After sorting the vector this will remove all duplicates:

```
void RemoveDuplicates(std::vector<int>& vector) 
{
    std::sort(vector.begin(),vector.end());
    auto it = std::unique(vector.begin(),vector.end());
    vector = std::vector<int>(vector.begin(),it);
}
```

A `std::set` stores only unique elements, hence can be used too:

```
void RemoveDuplicates2(std::vector<int>& vector) 
{
    std::set<int> s{vector.begin(),vector.end()};
    vector = std::vector<int>(s.begin(),s.end());
}
```

If you want to keep the initial ordering of the elements you can still use a `std::set`:

```
void RemoveDuplicates3(std::vector<int>& vector) 
{
    std::set<int> s;
    std::vector<int> result;
    for (const auto& e : vector) {
        if (s.insert(e).second) { // not a duplicate
            result.push_back(e);
        }
    }
    vector = result;
}
```

And very similar, by searching the elements not in the set but in the result vector:

```
void RemoveDuplicates4(std::vector<int>& vector) 
{
    std::vector<int> result;
    for (const auto& e : vector) {
        if (std::find(result.begin(),result.end(),e) == result.end()){
            result.push_back(e);
        }
    }
    vector = result;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/soeTercoc)

Answer (score 0):

Resizing an array (including vectors) in-place and shifting items over by 1 each time a duplicate is found can be expensive.

If you can use a hash table based collection (i.e. unordered_set or unordered_map) to keep track of items already seen, you can have an O(N) based algorithm.

Aside from the std::unqiue solution already suggested, it's hard to beat this.  std::unique is effectively the same thing.

```
void RemoveDuplicates(std::vector<int>& vec)
{
    std::unordered_set<int> dupes;
    std::vector<int> vecNew;
    for (int x : vec)
    {
        if (dupes.insert(x).second)
        {
            vecNew.push_back(x);
        }
    }
    vec = std::move(vecNew);
}
```

Comment: std::unordered_set is not a vector.

Comment: Alternatively, `if (dupes.insert(x).second)` eliminates the double search done by the find + insert (which also does a search).

Answer (score 0):

For starters the second parameter of the function is redundant and not used within the function. Remove it. The function should be declared like

```
void RemoveDuplicates( std::vector<int> &vector );
```

Also you forgot to change the original vector.

And it seems you mean inequality in the if condition

```
if (vector.at(i) != vector.at(j))
{
    tempVec.push_back(vector.at(i));  //Unduplicated Vector
}
```

instead of the equality

```
if (vector.at(i) == vector.at(j))
{
    tempVec.push_back(vector.at(i));  //Unduplicated Vector
}
```

Though in any case it is an incorrect logic within the inner for loop.

Your inner for loop is always start from 1

```
for (j = 1; j < vector.size(); j++)
```

So for this source vector `{ 1, 2, 3, 3 }` the value `2` will be pushed once on the tempVec and for each element with the value 3 there will be pushed two values equal to 3 to tempVec.

Using your approach the function can look the following way.

```
void RemoveDuplicates( std::vector<int> &vector ) 
{
    std::vector<int> tempVec; 

    for ( std::vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i < vector.size(); i++ )
    {
        std::vector<int>::size_type j = 0;

        while ( j < tempVec.size() && vector.at( i ) != tempVec.at( j ) )
        {
            ++j;
        }

        if ( j == tempVec.size() )
        {
            tempVec.push_back( vector.at( i ) );
        }
    }

    std::swap( vector, tempVec );
}
```

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void RemoveDuplicates( std::vector<int> &vector ) 
{
    std::vector<int> tempVec; 

    for ( std::vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i < vector.size(); i++ )
    {
        std::vector<int>::size_type j = 0;

        while ( j < tempVec.size() && vector.at( i ) != tempVec.at( j ) )
        {
            ++j;
        }

        if ( j == tempVec.size() )
        {
            tempVec.push_back( vector.at( i ) );
        }
    }

    std::swap( vector, tempVec );
}

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 1, 2, 3, 3 };

    std::cout << v.size() << ": ";
    for ( const auto &item : v )
    {
        std::cout << item << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    RemoveDuplicates( v );

    std::cout << v.size() << ": ";
    for ( const auto &item : v )
    {
        std::cout << item << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

The program output is

```
4: 1 2 3 3 
3: 1 2 3
```